# Combine Webpack runtime chunk with entrypoint chunk

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am using `runtimeChunk: "single"` which creates a separate runtime chunk. I want it to combine with app entrypoint chunk as it is going to load in every pages, so i don't want to load runtime chunk separately.

`webpack.config.js` :

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/app.ts"
    // ... other entries
  }
  // ... other configs
  optimization: {
    // = { name: "runtime" }
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          name: "commons",
          chunks: "initial",
          minChunks: 2
        },
        vendors: {
          chunks: "initial",
          name: "vendors",
          test: /node_modules\//,
          minChunks: 5,
          priority: 10
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`build`

```
./build
    |- app.bundle.js
    |- runtime.js
    |- [...others].js
```

I want to combine runtime.js and app.bundle.js together